# How do I get a snapshot still of a video in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, html5-video, html5-canvas

I am trying to write a nodejs server that will take a time input (possibly part of url path) and then provide a still of the video frame at that time index as a jpeg picture.

I can do this easily in plain Javascript, but I cant see a way to do this in nodejs. I know I will probably need to use a canvas plugin like node-canvas to do the snapshot.

Any ideas welcome.

The following is how I do it in Javascript at the moment:

myjavascript.js

```
function capture(video, scaleFactor) {
    if(scaleFactor == null){
        scaleFactor = 1;
    }
    var w = video.videoWidth * scaleFactor;
    var h = video.videoHeight * scaleFactor;
    stdout("<br/> w: "+ w+ "<br/> h: "+ h);
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width  = w;
        canvas.height = h;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, w, h);
    return canvas;
}

function shoot(){
 var video  = document.getElementById("videoTag");
 var output = document.getElementById("output");
 var canvas = capture(video, 1);
 output.innerHTML = '';
 output.appendChild(canvas);
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>video snap</title>   
    <script type="text/javascript" src="myjavascript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="video_container" >
        <video id="videoTag" width="640" height="360" autobuffer="" controls="true">
            <source src="frozenplanet.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            <source src="frozenplanet.ogv" type="video/ogg">
        </video>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Node.js hasn't video procesing tool and it's not recommended to process video by web-application. If you want to process video on the server side, you needs an appropriate tool for that and some queue realization (maybe on node) for it.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

[node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) has a nice `takeScreenshots` function.

```
var proc = new ffmpeg('/path/to/your_movie.avi')
  .takeScreenshots({
      count: 1,
      timemarks: [ '600' ] // number of seconds
    }, '/path/to/thumbnail/folder', function(err) {
    console.log('screenshots were saved')
  });
```

Comment: I would love to try this, seems more elegant than exec ffmpeg, however I cant get npm to install it or anything else at the moment :S

Comment: npm install fluent-ffmpeg
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/fluent-ffmpeg
    npm ERR! Error: failed to fetch from registry: fluent-ffmpeg
    ...
This is the error I get, checked proxy settings etc, all fine! :(

Comment: Well then try to fix that problem with npm because it is definitely better to have all the modules in userland available than having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Can you see the registry ok via npm, if I go to the registry url on a browser I can seen the json fine, however trying npm on any module gives me that, there are also posts appearing that suggest this may be something else. e.g. https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever/issues/216

Comment: It's happening with me too, and I have the latest version.

Comment: there is/was apparently some issue with npm handling of proxys, so when I tried it in an environment that does not have proxy it worked fine.

Comment: Further investigation has shown that the npm code plays havoc with https over proxy. You can solve this by doing the following:                "npm --proxy http://proxy-address:port/ --registry=http://registry.npmjs.org install fluent-ffmpeg"

Comment: hi when i use node-fluent-ffmpeg i got a err says "meta data contains no durations, aborting screenshot creation" any idea why?

Comment: I'd look at the usage for it and make sure I'm not doing anything the wrong way. If you're still getting the error, open an issue.

Comment: There is no such API in the latest version of the library. The callback method will not be called.

Comment: where do you specify the size?

Comment: See the answer by Steven Westmoreland for the correct answer in 2021. The API changed

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [node-fluent-ffmpeg](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#screenshotsoptions-dirname-generate-thumbnails) module for this. You'll need to install ffmpeg; on MacOS, install [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) then use the `brew install ffmpeg` command.

```
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

ffmpeg('/path/to/video.mp4')
  .on('end', function() {
    console.log('Screenshots taken');
  })
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  })
  .screenshots({
    // Will take screenshots at 20%, 40%, 60% and 80% of the video
    count: 4,
    folder: '/path/to/output'
  });
```

Comment: What will be the name of the screenshot? How can we set a custom thumbnail name?

Comment: just add `filename: 'name-of-file.png'` to the screenshot function

Answer (score 3):

As 'node-fluent-ffmpeg' wasn't not working for me for some reason, I figured this out myself - based on the code of [video-thumb](https://github.com/vdemedes/node-video-thumb) (which also wasn't working for me). You do need to install FFMPEG before you can use this code, [here](http://www.renevolution.com/how-to-install-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x/) is tutorial on how to do so for Mac.

```
var path = require('path'), // Default node module
    pathToFile = path.join(__dirname, 'folder', 'file.mov'),
    pathToSnapshot = path.join(__dirname, 'folder', 'file-snapshot.jpg');

// Also a default node module
require('child_process').exec(('ffmpeg -ss 00:00:25 -i ' + pathToFile + ' -vframes 1 -q:v 2 ' + pathToSnapshot), function () {

    console.log('Saved the thumb to:', pathToSnapshot);

});
```