# how to generate video thumbnail in node.js?

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, thumbnails

I am building an app with node.js, I successfully uploaded the video, but I need to generate a video thumbnail for it. Currently I use node exec to execute a system command of ffmpeg to make the thumbnail.

```
   exec("C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i Video/" + Name  + " -ss 00:01:00.00 -r 1 -an -vframes 1 -f mjpeg Video/" + Name  + ".jpg")
```

This code is coming from a tutorial from http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-resumable-video-uploade-in-node-js/

the code above did generate a jpg file but it's not a thumbnail but a video screen shot, I wonder is there any other method to generate video thumbnail, or how to exec the ffmpeg command to make a real thumbnail (resized), and I prefer png file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resize by adding a -s widthxheight option to your command.

Comment: well it works, but is this the only way to do  this,i mean do i really have to use exec, is there a node module to handle this problem

Answer (score 20):

[Reference to GitHub fluent-ffmpeg project](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg).

Repeating example from [original StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804408/621690):

```
var proc = new ffmpeg('/path/to/your_movie.avi')
  .takeScreenshots({
      count: 1,
      timemarks: [ '600' ] // number of seconds
    }, '/path/to/thumbnail/folder', function(err) {
    console.log('screenshots were saved')
  });
```

Comment: what is `count:1` here ??

Comment: quoting the documentation: "count: specifies how many thumbnails to generate. When using this option, thumbnails are generated at regular intervals in the video (for example, when requesting 3 thumbnails, at 25%, 50% and 75% of the video length). count is ignored when timemarks or timestamps is specified."

Comment: can that /path/to/your_movie.avi be a URL?

Answer (score 2):

There is a node module for this:
[video-thumb](https://github.com/vdemedes/node-video-thumb)

It basically just wraps a call to exec ffmpeg

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg to call ffmpeg from Node.js

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would recommend using [thumbsupply](https://www.npmjs.com/package/thumbsupply). In addition to provide you with thumbnails, it caches them to improve performance significantly.

```
npm install --save thumbsupply
```

After installing the module, you can use it in a following way.

```
const thumbsupply = require('thumbsupply')("com.example.application");

thumbsupply.generateThumbnail('some-video.mp4')
.then(thumb => {
    // serve thumbnail
})
```

Comment: keep an eye on the install command since thumbsupply has 3 'p'

Answer (score 0):

Using [media-thumbnail](https://www.npmjs.com/package/media-thumbnail), you can easily generate thumbnails from your videos. The module basically wraps the ffmpeg thumbnail functionality.

```
const mt = require('media-thumbnail')

mt.forVideo(
  './path/to/video.mp4',
  './path/to/thumbnail.png', {
    width: 200
  })
  .then(() => console.log('Success'), err => console.error(err))
```

You can also create thumbnails from your images using this package.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as thumbsupply from 'thumbsupply'; 
     const thumbNail = await thumbsupply.default.generateThumbnail("video(720p).mp4", {
        size: thumbsupply.default.ThumbSize.LARGE,
        timestamp: '10%',
        forceCreate: true,
        mimetype: 'video/mp4',
      });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
app.post('/convert', upload.any(), (req, res) => {
    console.log("calling", req.files)
    let thumbNailName = req.files[0].filename.split('.')
    var gm = require('gm');

    gm('./src/Upload/'+req.files[0].filename)// get pdf file from storage folder
    .thumb(
        50, // Width
        50, // Height
        './src/thumbnail/'+thumbNailName[0]+'.png', // Output file name
        80, // Quality from 0 to 100
        function (error, stdout, stderr, command) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log("processing");
            } else {
                console.log("error")
            }
        }
    );
})
```