# How can I get thumbnail of MP4 file using NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to get thumbnail image from a MP4 file.

I tried with MP4Box and it did not return any image.

```
var MP4Box = require('mp4box').MP4Box;
var mp4box = new MP4Box();
var arrayBuffer = new Uint8Array(fs.readFileSync('a.mp4')).buffer;
arrayBuffer.fileStart = 0;
mp4box.appendBuffer(arrayBuffer);
console.log(mp4box.getInfo());
```

Is it posible to get thumbnail using JS? And how can I do it?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Judging by the MP4Box readme, you have to wait for the `onReady` callback.

Comment: [`ffmpeg`](https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg) has a `takeScreenshots` member.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I found the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14348193/8467423