# How to generate video thumbnail in Microsoft Azure function using Nodejs?

Tags: node.js, azure, containers, azure-functions, devops

This image thumbnail generator function is trigger when uploading an image to blob container and works fine **but I don't how to do the same process for the video!**

```
    var Jimp = require("jimp");

     module.exports = (context, myBlob) => {

    // Read image with Jimp
    Jimp.read(myBlob).then((image) => {

        // Manipulate image
        image
            .resize(200, Jimp.AUTO) 
            .greyscale()
            .getBuffer(Jimp.MIME_JPEG, (error, stream) => {

                // Check for errors
                if (error) {
                    context.log(`There was an error processing the image.`);
                    context.done(error);
                }
                else {
                    context.log(`Successfully processed the image`);

                    // Bind the stream to the output binding to create a new blob

                    context.done(null, stream);

                }

            });

    });


};
```

Comment: Does this answer help?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804408/7743705

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple `node modules` that can help you generate thumbnails from video.
You could use any of the following:

1. Video Thumbnail Generator (https://www.npmjs.com/package/video-thumbnail-generator)
2. fluent-ffmpeg https://www.npmjs.com/package/fluent-ffmpeg/v/1.7.0#generating-thumbnails

In your case, since you are planning to generate thumbnails for both an image and a video, I would recommend using `fluent-ffmpeg` since it has capabilities to deal with both images and video using the `withsize()` method.

However, on the downside, in order to be able to use this module, make sure you have ffmpeg installed on your system (including all necessary encoding libraries like libmp3lame or libx264).

An example of how `fluent-ffmpeg` allows you to generate thumbnails is:

```
const FFmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');

new FFmpeg({ source: '/path/to/video.avi' })
    .withSize('320x240')
    .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
    })
    .on('end', function(filenames) {
        console.log('Successfully generated ' + filenames.join(', '));
    })
    .takeScreenshots(5, '/path/to/directory');
```