# Is it possible to get the first frame as image form video store in Firebase storage?

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

As the title it is, is there any way i can get the first frame pic form video store in firebase?

I have been try few way and none of them work out( adding #t=1s in the end of url ...)

Comment: Based on just the URL this would not be possible. Depending on the file format you use, you could download a small range of bytes from the start of the video and process them into an image. However, pulling the first frame for a thumbnail would not be useful in most cases anyway - YouTube generates start/middle/end thumbnails. Better options would be to [generate them on the client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23640869) when first uploaded or use a [server side solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8804408) in something like a Cloud Storage Cloud Function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking if there is any way to get only a subset of data for some file in Cloud Storage using a Firebase download URL, that is not possible at all.  A download URL is only capable of downloading the entire contents of any file.

If you need some sort of intermediate processing, you'll have to create your own API endpoint that performs the extraction.  There is no service provided by Firebase or GCP to do this for you.